# Optimize phonebook contact image before retrieving

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have used this piece of code for getting a persons contact image from iphone phonebook

```
CFDataRef imgData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)imgData];
CFRelease(imgData);
```

Some users add a contact image that is more than 2 or 3 MB in size.
what i want to do is to get an optimized image, like 250 x 250 resolution so that i dont get any memory issues which i'm facing now.

I managed to find this piece of code on http://blog.logichigh.com/2008/06/05/uiimage-fix/
It does the job. But when scaling an image more than 3.5MB on an iPhone 3G, the app crashes. So i was hoping if there is some code that would do this job better (not that the one below is not good) or if there is a way to get an optimized contact image, like some api.

Thank you for reading.

```
UIImage *scaleAndRotateImage(UIImage *image)
{
    int kMaxResolution = 320; // Or whatever
    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);enter code here
    if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
        CGFloat ratio = width/height;
        if (ratio > 1) {
            bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
        }
        else {
            bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
        }
    }
    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
    CGFloat boundHeight;
    UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    switch(orient) {
        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;
        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
    }
    else {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    }
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return imageCopy;
}
```

Comment: ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(recordRef, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. May be for someone like me who dint know about this.
While working with ios4.x you can use ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(recordRef,kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail) to get the thumbnail version of the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at Trevor Howard's great post about resizing `UIImage`s.

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Hope it helps.

**OR**, you can implement this class method:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```